# Setting pointer to const object after creating object

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

```
class a
{
    const std::string * ptr;
    void setPtr(const std::string & text)
    {
       ptr = &text; //it's wrong, I can set something to the pointer only at definition
    }
}
```

What's the solution? The pointer to my object must be const (class a's object must not modify it), but I need to change the pointer (what it points at) at runtime.

Comment: I'm confused. You can't modify it, but need to change it?

Comment: @Marc Glisse discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: What does this have to do with C++11?

Comment: @David it's that I accept c++11 solutions, but in this case I see the code is okay and I have bug in my code with consts.

Comment: I don't see what gets discarded. That's a usual issue when people don't post their real code but only what they think is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either left off a `const` in your sample:

```
void setPtr(const std::string & text) const
```

or you're calling `setPtr` on something `const`,

```
const a* foo = something;
foo->setPtr(somestring);
```

There are basically three rules:

You can't modify a non-const `a` instance through a `const` member function.
You can't modify a non-const `a` instance through a `const` pointer or reference to it.
You can't modify a `const` `a` instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with your current code. This line

```
const std::string * ptr;
```

means `ptr` is a pointer to a `const std::string`. `ptr` itself is not constant, so you can change what it points to.

See [this working demo](http://ideone.com/7c2nSM)

Comment: I see. So it's something wrong with my code as I get discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]....

Comment: @user1873947 Probably something wrong with code you aren't showing.